# IIs it possible to store data to server in files without using server side technology

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with the situation where I need to store some generic file on server but it's just an SCORM packages (interactive HTML & JS files).

Is it possible to store data in this file by using JS only.

Or any other technique. but not using server side technologies(like PHP).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. JS runs on the client (unless you're using Node, but that's server side). It can only pass data to the server. You need server side code to run to process the received data.

Comment: I cann't use PHP and make simple scripts to modify files on the server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thanks for your comment. Okay, I will find work around for this.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You want to store something serverside without using serverside technology which is obviously impossible. If the file only needs to be retrieved by the client later use localstorage for example.

Comment: If you want to modify a file on a server... you need a server :) It's as simple as that.

Comment: Well HTTP PUT would be a possible option ... but you’d still have to at least _configure_ the server to enable that.

Comment: X/Y Problem.  You are not stuck in a situation where you need to store something on a server.  You're in a situation where you need to store something.  If you do need to store it on a server then you *need* server-side code.  If you don't need to store it on a server then you can store it locally.

Comment: @Archer, Actually I need to store the data in file which is shared by multiple user, Also same file will be updated by multiple users. I will go with node.js.

Thanks for your help/time. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for server side you have to use server side language. There are many options other than PHP. One is **Node.js**. It is a JavaScript framework for writing server-side applications.

Comment: I will go with this. Thanks for your time.